# I think some of my comments were removed - can I find out?

Tags: support, comments

I seem to remember commenting on a question a day or two ago, but didn't see that comment when I visited it again today. I remember atleast one other time this happened in the past.

Given what I remember of what I said, it may be that it was too chatty or joking, or maybe offensive or sarcastic, I'm not sure - is there a way I can see any comments of mine that have been removed?

I'd like to be sure I've not broken any particular rules, and be sure that what I *am* writing in comments in the future doesn't go against what is acceptable.

*Please note I'm not asking for a reason, I'm sure the mods have enough to do without giving reasons for individual comment removal each time.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comments are ok. For reference, between the two posts you had commented on, there are 27 deleted comments and about 5-10 more still there.

In one case, a bunch of them were [move to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30252/discussion-on-question-by-byod-anon-should-i-be-concerned-about-the-byod-policy).

As moderators, we delete a *lot* of comments fitting the "when shouldn't I comment?" section below. Anything that hits the "Hot Network Questions" list pretty much gets 50+ deleted comments (many of which ARE in fact offensive/rude/completely inappropriate), nearly all of which are not fulfilling the intended use of comments.

Related references on this:

> [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/193412)
>
> Comments exist so that users can talk about questions and answers without posting new answers that do not actually answer their parent questions. Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, suggest corrections to and provide meta-information about posts.
>
> Comments are intentionally short, having maximum length of 600 characters, and allow only limited markup. URLs in comments automatically become hyperlinks. Each user may post only one comment every 15 seconds.
>
> **Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags.**

Also, from the Help Center [about comments](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When should I comment**?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>   When shouldn't I comment?
>
> **Comments are not recommended for any of the following**:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation & further info. one thing is unclear though - could you confirm if someone would be notified if their comment was deleted as the result of an offensive flag or similar?

Comment: @jammypeach no, that unfortunately doesn't exist (I wish it did... trust me, I wish it did...).  Generally though, if someone is making enough inappropriate comments to cause problems they get a warning message explaining what comments they made that were inappropriate, etc. And in case you are curious, I expect anyone worried/interested enough in posting a meta post like this would not make any of the comments to get themselves in trouble.

Comment: Check out [this meta post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322) and the [Be Nice](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy have perfect guidance on this.